# Prove: sum of angles in triangle is invariant

Tags: geometry

Prove that the sum of angles in any plane triangle is invariant, without invoking the fact that the sum of angles in a triangle is two right angles.

I've tried. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible without using some version of the parallel postulate, which the two right angles statement is.  Without the parallel postulate, you can have spherical geometry, where the sum of angles in a triangle is not constant.

Comment: @Anal, there is no way of doing that in an axiomatic system. Furthermore, the standard non-Euclidean geometry can be conformally modeled in subsets of the plane.

Comment: What is the axiom you are proposing to specify that?  I assumed you were using the Euclidean geometry axioms, but excluding the parallel postulate.  The parallel postulate, in essence, says everything happens in a plane, so you are using the two right angles if you do.

Comment: @Anal, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry#Models_of_the_hyperbolic_plane

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on the parallel postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate) lists a number of equivalents.  Yours is number 2 on the list.  From any equivalent we can derive number 2 and be done.

Comment: I was looking at the two right angles.  You are right that what you are asking to prove is number 4.

Comment: Yes, all of these in the list and many more are provably equivalent, in that if you assume any one plus the rest of the Euclidean axioms you can derive all the rest.  I believe these results date back hundreds of years, to when people were trying to derive the parallel postulate from the other axioms.  One way to work on that is to find as many equivalents as you can.  One of them may inspire you to find the proof you seek.  The development of non-Euclidean geometry proved that was impossible.  I know nothing about current research in this area.